# Abstract superlcass help

Tags: java

A is an abstract superclass of the concrete classes B and C. Constructors of all
three classes do not take parameters. The following variables are defined:

```
A a;
B b;
C c;
```

Which one or more of the following assignments will result in an error at
compile time?

```
(i) a = new C();
(ii) b = new C();
(iii) a = new A();
(iv) b = (B) new A();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Homework? What have you worked out so far? Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: Is this homework?  What is your answer?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.  You could at least say what you think the answers are.

Comment: and what you get when you tried?

Comment: These were the scenarios again.

Comment: (i) a = new C();
(ii) b = new C();
(iii) a = new A();
(iv) b = (B) new A();
(v) b = new B();

I believe that iii, iv and i are incorrect. is this right?

Comment: ii, iii and iv will fail compilation, you cannot instansiate an abstract class. and you cannot cast a superclass to a concrete class no matter if it is abstract or not.

Answer (score 2):

A is abstract so ANY attempt to create an A outright will fail. Also, the relationship between B and C is not clearly defined but I am betting the second case will fail as well unless B is a superclass of C.

Comment: B and C are only linked to the abstract superclass of A. they are separate

Comment: There a C can not be assigned to a B.

Answer (score 0):

Because A is an abstract superclass of B and C, A cannot be initialized. However, its subclasses can be stored in an object of the type of the superclass (A), since it shares or defines the methods contained in A.

Should be enough to figure it out.